# Why would China and UK peacefully agree Hong Kong to be returned to UK?

Tags: alternate-history

At mid-night  1 July 1997, UK returned HK to China. Call my imaginary China's handover to UK "Patriation" - it must happen after 1 July 1997.

As we know from real world 2019 protests, some Hongkongers prefer UK rule. China wants HK and doesn't want give it back to UK. UK doesn't plan to get HK back.

What's smallest change to history that accomplishes Patriation? Just 3 constraints -

1. There can't be conflict or war that leads to bloodshed, pain, and suffering. But of course there can be economic or trade wars.
2. Reason must be realistic...no mind control, no super weapons, etc!
3. China and UK are like their present formats.  Both must gaily, gleefully, purposely, voluntarily agree Patriation.

Comment: Whew! that's some ask you've got there! not a clue but I'll be following this one with interest to see what miracles anyone else pulls out of a hat [pulls up a chair & reaches for some popcorn].

Comment: You may find yourself closed as off-topic again though.

Comment: I've often seen the original agreement characterized as a "lease", which implies that the most likely answer is a big stack of cash. (It so often is...) But I'll freely admit that I don't know if that makes sense in the context of why it was handed back in the first place.

Comment: @Pelinore I mean we should really close this... but maybe we should wait a while, to see if anything interesting comes up [pulls up a chair and grabs some popcorn]. OP, I hope you understand that these types of questions are not appropriate here. Your building a world and control the narrative. Winnie the Pooh could sneeze and that would be enough to hand over control if you, the narrator, wanted it to happen.

Comment: @Shadowzee "What's the smallest change to history" should be in scope  for worldbuilding. The OP isn't indulging in whimsical fantasy, but minimalist alternative history.

Comment: Three words: Hong Kong Gandhi.

Comment: Why are you set on the handoff having taken place?  The simplest change would be for the 99 year lease to have had a renewal clause...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The UK goes bankrupt from the economic devastation caused by Brexit and other things. Its alliance with the US is breaks due to more US-induced disasters in the Middle East and the continuing unreliability of the United States as a partner (maybe Trump wins another term). It needs a new friend. China steps into the role. Chinese investments begin to revitalize the UK economy. The leaders of the UK sign a military alliance with China. China establishes military bases in the UK. The UK moves from the American sphere of influence to the Chinese one. As a sign of good will, China allows the UK to station some of its army in Hong Kong and places the UK in charge of governing Hong Kong. Much gay, gleeful celebration is had.

Comment: The question asks "what's the smallest change to history". Your answer is chock-a-block with maximal and multiple changes to history. Sorry, to rain on your parade.

Comment: Actually, the question is "What's the smallest change to history that accomplishes X?" where X is something that's quite implausible. In fact, I would say this is the smallest change that could let X happen in a reasonable way. Not saying that this is "small", but if you ask for the implausible, you can't complain if it takes something serious to make it happen.

Comment: Not something serious, a series of somethings even more implausible than the event sought by the OP. It does work as comedy writing.

Comment: As comedic as Donald Trump becoming president. But much more plausible.

Comment: And the UK also sails into the Atlantic and leaves Europe, right?

Comment: @MartinSchröder In 11 days, in fact. Well, we'll see.

Comment: @Priska Or maybe not. Yet.

Answer (score 6):

Your condition 3 will be the main stumbing block. As it stands now, China is not disposed to abandon sovereignty over **any** part of China, and Hong Kong is a part of China. In the 19th century foreign powers carved China into *spheres of influence* while China was unable to resist. The Chinese (and not just the top government officials) are quite determined that this will not happen again. So:

- It would have to be clear that China is not *forced* to *surrender* any sovereign rights. Say the Taiwan and Tibet issues have been settled to the mainland's satisfaction before, which probably means undisputed sovereignty.
- There would have to be clear economic advantages for China in doing so, which overcome national pride and sovereignty. Say the Brits are still in the EU and the EU28 would agree to free trade through Hong Kong if Hong Kong formally becomes part of the UK. There would have to be confidence that the economic advantages are long-lasting.

Your alternate history could be made more likely if China were to become more capitalist, less nationalist. But even capitalists feel national pride.

Comment: Liked your summary of China & its sovereignty issues. It gives the reasons why the PRC wouldn't give up HK. Historically capitalism & nationalism rose together. Nationalism has always been good public relations for capitalist nations. Whatever else China has to gain more of *something* to handback HK.

Answer (score 6):

The most probable circumstance to make a handover of Hong Kong (HK) back to the UK is if China itself wants this to happen.

Assuming the ongoing civil unrest and uprising continues in HK, and this and other decisions made by the current PRC leadership are considered to be poor. The poorness of the decisions is as seen by members of the Chinese Communist Party (CCP). These could failures in the Trade Wars, other international political setbacks, general weakness in China's economy, and setbacks with the belt and Road Initiative. Assume this leads to coup replacing the current leadership and that as a way of quietening Chinese national and international unrest, HK could be relinquished. This could accompanied by a resurgence in what can be called Deng Xiao Ping Though where the PRC works quietly and unobtrustively in its rise in the world.

Rather than allow HK to be an ongoing thorn in the side of the Chinese body politic, a decision could be made to return HK to the UK. British political leadership would see this as a triumph for Britain and be willing to resume territorial status of HK. Remember the UK previously had permanent sovereignty over Hong Kong island and Kowloon. It was only the New territories which was held with a Ninety-Nine (99) Year lease.

In conclusion, political change at the top levels of CCP, possibly with a change in leadership, which may or may not be part of a coup at the government level, could necessitate a handback of Hong Kong to the United Kingdom by the PRC itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Chinese Revolution.**

The needle swings back, and hardline communists once again take control of the government, reversing market reforms, quashing freedoms, and reverting China to the worker's paradise of the 1960s.

But this time the workers aren't having it.  The populace rises up in revolution.  Chaos ensues and when the dust settles a provisional Chinese government backed by foreign powers is in place to establish order, prevent famine and keep the nuclear weapons from wandering off.

Some areas are less disrupted than others and in many of these, local governments take matters into their own hands to protect their populace.  Hong Kong is one of these.  Familiar with the UK and in need of military help to control the crush of refugees and incursions by would-be warlords, Hong Kong petitions for patriation back to the UK and the new Chinese government readily agrees.  It has a lot on its plate and it needs the help too.